Are the groups $(\mathbb{R}-\{0\}, \cdot)$ and $(\mathbb{R}-\{-1\}, *)$ isomorphic?
Let the groups $(\mathbb{R}-\{0\}, \cdot)$ and $(\mathbb{R}-\{-1\}, *)$, where $x*y=x+y+xy$ for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}-\{-1\}$. Prove that these groups are isomorphic.
I found this $\varphi$ bijective function between both sets, where $\varphi(x)=\frac{x-1}{x}$ however I see that it is not an homomorphism ($\varphi(x\cdot y)\neq \varphi(x)*\varphi(y)=\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)+\varphi(x)\cdot \varphi (y) $).
My question is: is this function sufficient to prove that both groups are isomorphic? or how can I find a bijective homomorphism between both groups?
Thanks for your help ;)

How can a function which is not an homomorphism prove the the groups are isomorphic?

Regarding your first question (is this function sufficient), here is a question to ask yourself: If the existence of the $\varphi$ were enough to prove that the two groups are isomorphic, would you would be willing to apply this method on any two groups between which there exists a bijection?


Your function is not enough to prove the groups are isomorphic, because it's not an isomorphism.

Hint: An isomorphism will preserve inverses, so that if $\varphi(a) = x$ then $\varphi(a^{-1}) = x^{-1}$.  In the first group the inverse of a number $a$ is $\frac1a$. In the second group, what is the inverse of a number $x$?


